# Big-O recurrence relation

Tags: big-o, recurrence

So my recurrence relationis is as follow:

```
T(n) = O(1) if n < 100

T(n) = 2T(n/3) + n otherwise
```

I used the iteration method and as result i have that the big-O is:

```
O(n^(log in base 3 of n))
```

It seems a little bit weird to me (expecially for the exercises i'm used to), but is it correct?

<strike>If you need my steps i will add them (don't know how to format the text for summations and stuff, but if it's needed i will try)</strike>

Edit:

By applying the iteration method i find that T(n) at step 'i' is equal to

```
T(n) = (2^i)T(n/(3^i)) + n * (sum from k = 0 to i of (2/3)^k)
```

Since i = log base 3 of n

```
T(n) = 2^(log base 3 of n) + n * (sum from k = 0 to log base 3 of n of(2/3)^k)
```

The sum is O((2/3)^log base 3 of n). If i multiply that for n i get

```
O(n^(log base 3 of n))
```

That is my old result. Thanks to 'yuvgin' i noticed that first i can change base:

```
(2/3)^log base 3 of n = n ^ log base 3 of (2/3)
```

And then i can simplify the log base 3 of (2/3)

```
n ^ log base 3 of (2/3) = n ^ ((log base 3 of 2) - (log base 3 of 3))
```

Log base x of x is equal to 1 so:

```
O(n^log base 3 of 2)
```

Edit2:

So i found this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742712/how-to-solve-the-recurrence-tn-2tn-3n

That explains how my summation is O(n), but shouldn't my result be correct too, since it's assuming the sum is less then or equal to the same sum but infinite?

Comment: Your result does seem odd (the correct answer is simply `O(n)`) – please show the steps you took.

Comment: Added the steps, i even tried with the recursion tree and i get the same result, but i can't understand why my friends with the master theorem gets O(n)